# list of tuples to single list

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, python-collections

I have list of tuples in the following format,

```
[('ABC', ['32064', ['WOO', 'MISSI']]),
('XYZ', ['32065', ['HAY']])]
```

I need to convert them into following format,

```
[['ABC','32064','Woo'],
['ABC','32064','MISSI'],
['XYZ','32065','HAY']]
```

I have tried the following code

```
list1=[[('ABC', ['32064', ['WOO', 'MISSI']]),
('XYZ', ['32065', ['HAY']])]]
list2 = [item for sublist in list1 for item in sublist]
list2
```

but still producing the same result.

Comment: Have you tried doing it? If so, add the code for your attempt to the question

Comment: yes edited my code with my approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with a list comprehension:

```
data = [('ABC', ['32064', ['WOO', 'MISSI']]),
('XYZ', ['32065', ['HAY']])]

[[t[0],t[1][0],x] for t in data for x in t[1][1]]
```

Output:

```
[['ABC', '32064', 'WOO'], ['ABC', '32064', 'MISSI'], ['XYZ', '32065', 'HAY']]
```